# Error While Using Realm in React Native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

React Native app works fine on emulator (with debugging + without debugging) and also on Android device (without debugging). But when I connect app with chrome for debugging, it's giving below error:
Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://192.168.1691.130/create_session'

React Native Version:
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.42.3